# Code not compiling in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code and it is getting compiled on my PC with Python3. But Showing error while uploading to Codechef server. Please suggest, I am coding for the first time in Python 3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run-ls7W2DcLmzUs9GNKbLGN/solution.py", line 41, in <module>
    l,r,k=map(int,input().split())
  File "<string>", line 1
    9 23 1
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using python2.x which evaluates the string you enter for `input`.  Change the function from `input` to `raw_input` and you should be all set.

If you want the code to work for both python2.x and python3.x, you could do a simple little hack like this at the top of your script:

```
try:
    #This raises `NameError` on python3.x since `raw_input` is renamed to `input`
    input = raw_input
except NameError: 
    pass
```

It's not pretty, but it works (and I've used things like this on occasion).  Ultimately, this shadows the builtin `input` on python2.x, but that's really not a big deal.  You probably don't want to be using that builtin for any serious coding anyway.

Comment: Or actually use Python 3.x

Comment: If you're writing backwards compatible code, I'd recommend doing it the other way: `if sys.version_info >= (3,): raw_input = input`, so you don't confuse Python 2 programmers.

Comment: @RoadieRich -- Yeah, I've done that one too.  Tomato-tomato as far as I see it.  My way avoids an extra import, but that's probably not much of a concern for most scripts.